# How to get the fingerprint image from a 4000B DigitalPersona to SQL Database C#?

Tags: c#, sql, biometrics

I'm currently using digital Persona biometrics U.are.U 4000B fingerprint reader and I'm using Neurotechnology for its SDK. And I have a sample program that can get the fingerprint from the scanner but I don't have any idea how to get the fingerprint image from the neurotech database so I could store it in the SQL Database?

Comment: That's a fairly specialized request, so you're less likely to get an answer here (I could be wrong). I suggest you try contacting the manufacturer.

Comment: Without regard to the format of the data you are trying to save, you are really looking to store a Blob in the database. A simple Google search should aid you here.

Comment: I'm working with Neurotechnology as well at the moment, and this is not the right place for you to ask this. I would highly recommend the neurotechnology forum. It's the best resource for you and I'm saying this based on experience.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm getting in your request, you want to store the scanned image in an SQL DB right? Why do that when the samples provided in Neurotechnology actually store it in an "SQL Lite Database" for you. All you need is to find a way to link that database to your application.

Edit: the database will actually create the appropriate table for you and it stores the template as a blob so I think by that you'd be good to go.